# Return list/type/array of blobs in Oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, blob

Is there any way to return in function a few Blobs? For instance in array? I need to return a few pictures which I have in database in StillImage format. But to get mapped well I need to convert them to blobs. But I didn't find any kind of method to return an array of blobs, cause types in Oracle doesn't support complex types.

Comment: `create type t_blob as table of blob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what you mean when you say "types in Oracle don't support complex types".  You can certainly define a collection of BLOBs

```
SQL> create type blob_nt is table of blob;
  2  /

Type created.
```

and then write a function that returns this collection type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_blobs
  RETURN blob_nt
IS
BEGIN
  <<your logic>>
END;
```

Depending on the size of the BLOBs and what "few" means to you, however, it may make more sense to write a pipelined table function that pipes out individual BLOBs rather than loading multiple BLOBs into scarce PGA memory.

Comment: I found sth like a :
""It is currently a limitation of the OCI layer that only scalar types can be used for associative arrays. As such, blobs, clobs, timestamps, intervals, and I suppose xmltypes, cannot be used." Then I decided to not use type of blob. But do you think that can be able to return a ref cursor to blobs?
I've a table with name of birds. Then I've a table with images. One bird has got many images. So i would like to return in one function all images of one bird.

Comment: @Fred - That sounds like a limitation in your client API.  Can you describe your application architecture and explain what API(s) you're using to access the database?  I would expect that whatever client API you're using would support a pipelined table function that includes a BLOB column or a `SYS_REFCURSOR` that includes a BLOB column.

Comment: Ok, i think that I understand. I thought that it was impossible to return some blobs, but sys_refcursor also will be good. Thanks!